# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sinaweibopy3'

Tags: python, module

I'm trying to connect to Sina Weibo API.
I installed sinaweibopy3 on my python 3 jupyter notebook successfully.
But it threw me an error when I imported it.
Can anyone please help?

```
pip install sinaweibopy3
```

```
import webbrowser
import sinaweibopy3
```

Outcome:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-f119237e2791> in <module>
      1 import webbrowser
----> 2 import sinaweibopy3

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sinaweibopy3'
```

Answer (score 0):

The module name is `weibo.py`. Therefore you should type `import weibo`.